# Why does attacking this person make them talk about cake?

Tags: momodora-reverie-under-moonlight

I found a hidden room accessible with the cat transformation. Inside is a single person. When I attack them they either say "Aaaa... My cake..." or "Uu... Nohorn, go home!". Why does this person talk about cake and Nohorn when I attack them?  Is there some secret I'm missing?

[image: Person talking about cake]

[image: Map location]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character itself is a cameo from a comic called Himehorn. According to [this comment on Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/428550/discussions/0/412448792373039411/#c412449508275932551), the "no horn" thing appears in the comic. They also assume that the cake is what the character is eating. So it would make sense that the character is crying about it's cake after you hit it.

In another steam discussion, [a developer confirms](https://steamcommunity.com/app/428550/discussions/0/1744480966979830956/#c1744480966992487188) that the character is a cameo from a friend's comic. There is also a link to [this webpage](http://manga.clone-army.org/) which hosts different comics with this species (including Himehorn).